# Connect-SPOService : Could not authenticate to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, authentication

I am unable to connect to SPO from SharePoint online management shell  using my account.  MFA is enabled.

I'm executing the following command:

```
Connect-SPOService -url https://[URL].sharepoint.com
```

And I get the following response:

```
Connect-SPOService : Could not authenticate to SharePoint Online 
https://[URL].sharepoint.com/ using OAuth 2.0
    At line:1 char:1
    + Connect-SPOService -url https://[URL].sharepoint.com
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-SPOService], AuthenticationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.AuthenticationException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoi
    nt.PowerShell.ConnectSPOService
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following below Steps:

1. Open SharePoint Online management shell using **Run as administrator**.
2. Then try using below code:

```
    $UserName = "adminUser@domain.onmicrosoft.com"
    $SPOAdminCenterUrl = "https://domain-admin.sharepoint.com"

    $O365Cred = Get-Credential -UserName $UserName
    Connect-SPOService -Url $SPOAdminCenterUrl -Credential $O365Cred
```

**Note**: I have used URL of **SharePoint Online Administration Center** and not any other SharePoint site.

As per the [official documentation by Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/connect-sposervice),

> **Connect-SPOService** Connects a SharePoint Online global administrator to a SharePoint Online connection (the SharePoint Online Administration Center). This cmdlet must be run before any other SharePoint Online cmdlets can run.
>
> You must be a **SharePoint Online global administrator** to run the cmdlet.

You can read more about permissions, signle PowerShell session per Windows and parameters of this command using above link of official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> *Connect-SPOService* works on the yoursharepoint-admin.sharepoint.com sites. You need to be have access to that site which means you should
>   have administration rights on SharePoint in your subscription. Only
>   then you will be able to connect to the sites.

```
Connect-SPOService -url https://yourorgname-admin.sharepoint.com
```

After hitting this, it will prompt for user/password and MFA. If you are not a global administrator and still want to connect to your site, you can try using PnPOnline cmdlets given below.

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
```

This will install the PnP module and then SharePoint Online PnP cmdlets will be available for use. Hit the below cmdlet to connect to your site.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://yoursite.sharepoint.com -UseWebLogin
```

This will open a browser dialogue for your user/password and MFA. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) is the reference link from MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Run SharePoint Online Management Shell with system account.

For this commend: Connect-SPOService -url https://[URL].sharepoint.com, We must use URL of SharePoint Online Administration Center and not any other SharePoint site.

Getting started with SharePoint Online Management Shell:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps